# Getting absolute path of an Object

Tags: java, servlets, documentum

how to get the absolute path of given object id using java dfc in documentum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
IDfSysObject obj = (IDfSysObject)session.getObject(id);

String path = obj.getPath(0)
```

Note that you can use different parms in getPath() if your object has more than one content.